# Why I get a white screen ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I get a white screen with this code. Why this happens ?. I assigned the Column Widget to the body and it worked. But with the Positioned Widget it does not. I removed the background color but this does not solve the problem too.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MakeAppointment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MakeAppointmentState createState() => _MakeAppointmentState();
}

class _MakeAppointmentState extends State<MakeAppointment> {
  @override
  String _initial_value = "Name";

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70.0),
        child: AppBar(
          centerTitle: false,
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.76),
          elevation: 0,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text("Appointment for 1. January"),
        ),
      ),
        body: Positioned(
          right: 100,
          top: 50,
            child: TextField(
              maxLines: 1,
              cursorWidth: 5.5,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Name",
                border: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            )),


    );}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a `Container` instead of directly using the TextField as child element.

```
    body: Positioned(
      right: 100,
      top: 50,
        child: Container(
          child: TextField(
            maxLines: 1,
            cursorWidth: 5.5,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Name",
              border: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
              disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        )),
```

Comment: can you tell me how ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a stack widget and then add positioned widget as it's children.

Answer (score 0):

I soloved this issue by wrapping the TextField inside Flexibale

```
 Flexible(
          child: TextField(
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              controller: messageController,
              cursorColor: Colors.black,
              decoration: globals.inputDecoration("write message")),
        )
```